# Data Augmentation - Is shifting needed?

Tags: machine-learning

I can understand the power of data augmentation and the different ways of data augmentation like rotating, flipping, normalization, etc.

Is shifting the object around the image really needed? Will there be an difference in results of the convolution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, shifting an object is quite needed.

**If the object that you are trying to detect/classify is most of the times around the center of an image, then your model will probably adjust its weights, so that it focuses on searching the center of an image.**

You can force your model to search all the regions of an image, by shifting the targeted object around the image. Also, You can improve the model's training by changing the object's shape as well (e.g. you can **zoom** in the image).

This repository is a quite good introductory of commonly used data augmentations in object detection:
https://github.com/kochlisGit/random-data-augmentations

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that in the test data the images are always centered, then shifting might not be needed. But in real world, that is not the case.

[image]

For example you cant expect a cat to stay always at center of the image. In test data it might appear at any position. Your model will learn better if you consider such cases in your training data.

Note: The image above is just for easy understanding. Data has been augmented using rotation as well, not just shift. But it serves the purpose, so included it. ([Image Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/image-augmentation-for-deep-learning-histogram-equalization-a71387f609b2))

As far as difference in results is concerned, we can't be sure how significant will the change in the performance be until you try it out. But people find that shift helps improving performance, usually used along with flip, rotate, scale, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Centered Objects doesnot require shifting, but in real-world test data you might have objects that are not centred so in that case it becomes preety imortant.

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=10,
width_shift_range=0.1,
height_shift_range=0.1,
shear_range=0.15,
zoom_range=0.1,
channel_shift_range=10.,
horizontal_flip=True)
```